# ¿Cómo cambiar el color de un check de un checkbox?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, color

Con la propiedad accent-color se puede cambiar el color de los checkbox, radio, etc... pero me he encontrado que lo modifica el color del fondo, mientras que en el caso del check lo pone en negro o blanco en función del color del fondo que se elija en la propiedad accent-color, modificándolo en función de su legibilidad. ¿Sabéis si es posible modificar ese check con alguna propiedad del estilo de accent-color?

```html
<label><input style="accent-color:yellow" type="checkbox" checked/>Checkbox con fondo claro y check oscuro</label><br>
<label><input style="accent-color:darkred" type="checkbox" checked/>Checkbox con fondo oscuro y check claro</label>
```

Comment: Efectivamente como te dicen en la respuesta, lo mejor es que crees uno personalizado, así puedes cambiar todo lo que necesitas

Answer (score 0):

Podrias intentar creando uno personalizado usando CSS

```css
.custom-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.custom-checkbox + label {
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.custom-checkbox + label span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #EAECEF;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.custom-checkbox + label span::before {
  content: "";
  opacity: 0;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background-color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  right: auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.custom-checkbox:checked + label span::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.custom-checkbox:disabled + label {
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: default;
}

.custom-checkbox:disabled + label span {
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input class="custom-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="chkbx_1" value="1">
  <label for="chkbx_1">
    <span></span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, esa era la solución que habíamos pensado, pero antes queríamos saber si existía la posibilidad de hacerlo solo con css. Gracias!